# MineCraft freezes on Orcale Java but not openjdk

Tags: java, freeze, minecraft, jvm

So when I updated from 13.04 to 14.04 LTS (I do a clean reinstall of the new ubuntu version) and did minecraft on the first time using orcale java. When I started to launcher it froze ubuntu up and needed a restart(it really annoying). But when I tryed openjdk problem solved. But I need orcale JVM to use flare hacked client. I tried it already on openJDK it just got me a blank screen when I use a hacked client even nodus. I have notice that if I close all of the programs that are running it works. But when a program starts automatically (usually background process) it will freeze and it usually half to restart the computer again(did I say it was annoying?) so yea please help btw linux is the new windows

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft freezes with on my 14.04 box. The error message reports it is a problem with compiz. I am running with the generic video driver because there is no ATI driver fix for my card. It may be worth downloading cssm and see what tweaks can be made to compiz.